# Trouble having my RPS game show up with onClick button

Tags: python, html, github, onclick, syntax-error

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Play Rock Paper Scissors (MK Edition)</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="Play Rock Paper Scissors(MK Edition)">Play Rock Paper Scissors (MK Edition)</button>
<script>
function Play Rock Paper Scissors(MK Edition) {
// Get the path to the Python script.
var pythonScriptPath = "path/to/python/script.py";
  // Run the Python script.
  subprocess.run(["python", pythonScriptPath]);
}
```

I am receiving two syntax errors in my code when I am trying to have my rock paper scissor game pull up when I click the play button.

I'm still trying to rework it and look for any grammatical errors etc but I'm not sure if it's that. The error messages I see say "uncaught syntaxerror: missing ( before formal parameters" and "uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token: identifier". My expectations are when a user clicks on the play rock paper scissors button the rock paper scissors game prompts will pull up so you can play.

Comment: hello beezz, welcome to stackoverflow. in order to get help faster, you will need to show us what you have tried so far, with regards to your code so we can see where the problem is and try to help. maybe this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi @jeffreyohene, thank you! this is my first time posting a question so i'm all over the place. lol i was able to add the snippet of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from a first glance it seems you have a syntax error in your Javascript function name. you can't have spaces in the function name, and parentheses should be reserved for parameter declarations. you can apply these changes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Play Rock Paper Scissors (MK Edition)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="playRockPaperScissors()">Play Rock Paper Scissors (MK Edition)</button>
  <script>
    function playRockPaperScissors() {
      // Get the path to the Python script.
      var pythonScriptPath = "path/to/python/script.py";
      
      // Run the Python script.
      subprocess.run(["python", pythonScriptPath]);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the onClick attribute of the button now calls the playRockPaperScissors() function.

Comment: Oh okay I understand. How can I get the RPS game prompt to automatically start once I click the onClick attribute button? I wrote it in Python

Comment: seeing the Python code will help me gain a better idea of what you want to do.